# Unable to install Semantic UI Component for Angular CLI: 8.3.18?

Tags: semantic-ui, angular8

I'm using Angular CLI: 8.3.18 for my current project. Thus, after I create a new project `sudo ng new angular-reddit`, I tried to install Semantic UI Component because I need to use it for styling purpose.

So, I issued this command but ended up with and error as bellow

`npm i -g semantic-ui --save`

The output was

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of better-console@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of del@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of extend@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-autoprefixer@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-chmod@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-clean-css@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-clone@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-concat@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-concat-css@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-copy@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-dedupe@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-flatten@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-header@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-help@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-if@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-less@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-notify@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-plumber@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-print@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-rename@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-replace@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-rtlcss@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-uglify@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of gulp-watch@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of map-stream@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of replace-ext@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of require-dot-file@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of run-sequence@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui@2.4.2 requires a peer of yamljs@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/narun/.npm/_logs/2019-11-10T04_12_55_741Z-debug.log
```

I followed the provided [Url](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5) provided in console, but it still did not help solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly delete node if it is less than 10 and restart your PC

After that install node 12.13.0 atleast

Upgrade your angular cli using below command

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

After everything is done restart your PC and then it will work